# Validacion en PHP , como imprimir alertas en la pantalla

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo

En el Archivo cargarArchivos se realiza la petición de enviar un archivo de la siguiente manera :

```js
//Enviar Archivo

    peticion.open('post','subir.php');
    const url = 'subir.php';
    const files = document.getElementById('archivo').files
    const formData = new FormData()

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];

        //formData.append('archivo', file);
        formData.append('archivo', files[0]);
        formData.append('parametro', ruta_archivo);
        formData.append('parametro', tamanio_archivo);
        formData.append('parametro', extension_archivo);
        peticion.send(datos);

    }
```

del lado del php se recibe en el archivo subir.php  por POST

```html
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $_FILES['archivo'];
    $enviarParametros = json_decode($_POST['parametros'], true);
    $ruta = $enviarParametros['ruta'];
    $extensiones = $enviarParametros['extension'];
    $tamanio = $enviarParametros['tamanio'];

    $archivo = (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : null;
    if ($archivo){

        $all_files = count($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
            $archivo_nombre_base = $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i];
            $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i];
            $archivo_tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'][$i];
            $archivo_tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'][$i];
            $archivo_nombre_temporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i];


            $array = explode(".", $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i]);
            $archivo_extension = strtolower(end($array));

            $cambiar_nombre = null;
            $cambiar_nombre = sha1("ArchivoNuevo" . rand(0, 10000000));

            $archivo_nombre = $cambiar_nombre . "." . $archivo_extension;
            $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/ /', '_', $archivo_nombre);
            $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/%20/', '_', $archivo_nombre);
            $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/:/', '_', $archivo_nombre);


            if ($archivo_extension == $extensiones){

            } else{

                echo "Ups! $archivo_nombre_base, no es un archivo con extensión valido.$archivo_tipo";
                echo "<br/>";
                $errors[] = 'La extension no corresponde: ' . $archivo_nombre . ' ' . $archivo_tipo;
            }
           if ($archivo_tamanio >= $tamanio ) {
               echo"Ups! El tamaño de tu archivo $archivo_nombre_base, supera los $tamanio KBs permitidos.";

              $errors[] = 'El tamaño del archivo' . $archivo_nombre_base . ' excede el Maximo permitido' . $tamanio . 'en Kbs';
           }

            if (empty($errors)) {

                move_uploaded_file($archivo_nombre_temporal, $ruta . $archivo_nombre);
                echo "El archivo " . $archivo_nombre_base . " se ha cargado con éxito";

            }

        }

    }

}
```

ya intente con esta lineas

```js
echo "<script>
                alert('Ups! <b>$archivo_nombre_base</b>, no es un archivo con extensión valido.$archivo_tipo');
                window.location= 'url.php'
                </script>";
```

Se valida que corresponda la extensión y el tamaño, en caso que no cumpla envía los ecos,solo se muestran en la consola del navegador. ¿Como se pueden recuperar los ecos para que sean mostrados en la pantalla en el HTML?

Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo a preguntas anteriores, estás subiendo el archivo por AJAX y es necesario ver cómo es que quieres mostrar esos mensajes.

Comment: Buenas Tardes @Triby  el archivo y sus parametros se suben utilizando formdata y con el juego de sentencias y este: " peticion.send(datos); " , ya con los datos en el PHP se hace todo el proceso de manejo del archivo y al final utilizo las lineas indicadas para verificar que sea el tipo y el tamaño adecuado, en la consola me muestra los ecos , mas no me salen en la vista HTML

Comment: Sí, vecino, agrega el código de tu petición AJAX y donde manejas la respuesta para poder sugerirte algo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta crear una variable de sesión:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["alert"] = "Tu alerta";
```

Esto creará una variable de sesión válida en el siguiente `request`.

En tu vista puedes poner un script, para que detecte esa variable y, si existe, despliegue una alerta:

```html
<script>
    var msg = '{{ $_SESSION['alert'] }}';
    {{ unset( $_SESSION['notice'] }}
    if(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Especial cuidado en añadir la línea para borrar esa variable de sesión, si no aparecerá siempre.

Eso creará una alerta del navegador, y listo

Comment: No logre hacer que funcione , te agradezco la aportación , seguiré probando mas tarde y en caso que logre que funcione te doy tu positivo.  Saludos