# Como puedo recuperar el nombre que ha sido subido al servidor

Tags: php, html

después de que uno sube un archivo al servidor con `move_uploaded_file` como puedo recuperar el nombre de ese archivo subido para que se pueda mostrar en el HTML.

Este es mi codigo para subir el archivo:

```html
if (empty($errors)) {

                move_uploaded_file($archivo_nombre_temporal, $ruta . $archivo_nombre);
                echo "la ruta destino donde se guardo el archivo es: " . $ruta . $archivo_nombre;
                
            }
```

En la consola si me muestra ese echo..

la ruta destino donde se guardo el archivo es: la ruta . nombre_archivo.pdf

Investigando un poco encontré un código que recupera todos los archivos que se han guardado en la ruta indicada,

```
<?php
$directorio_escaneado = scandir('archivos/tmp');
$archivos = array();
foreach ($directorio_escaneado as $item) {
    if ($item != '.' and $item != '..') {
        $archivos[] = $item;
    }
}
echo json_encode($archivos);
?>
```

Este codigo lo utilice para probarlo y muestra sin problema todo el contenido de la carpeta indica en $ruta.

Yo solo necesito recuperar los valores o datos del archivo que se subió y  mostrarlo en pantalla.

Gracias

Saludos

Comment: No entiendo bien, si sabes que archivo se guardo, puedes mostrar ese nombre avisando que lo has subido, ahora si quieres verificar si el archivo ya existe, es lo mismo pero con `file_exists()`

Comment: Precisamente ese es mi problema, tengo un echo que me coloca la ruta  y el nombre del archivo que se subió, pero ese echo no he logrado que se muestre en el HTML.  el HTML esta en un archivo index.php ,  el php donde se sube el archivo se llama subir.php y un javascript administra ambas partes.

Comment: En ese caso, deberías mostrar TU código a ver como lo tienes. No un código que no sea tuyo.

Comment: Aquí puedes ver el código https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/402093/validacion-en-php-como-imprimir-alertas-en-la-pantalla?noredirect=1#comment719824_402093

Comment: dentro de ese mismo archivo podrias hacer la validacion de que si se envio o no se envio para simplemente guardar en la variable el mensaje

Comment: o simplemente retornar a la pagina con tu mensaje a traves del metodo get quedando algo asi como index.php?&mensaje=La&ruta&es&..

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que tengo entendido estas usando 2 archivos, uno para subir los archivos y validarlo y otro para mostrar un mensaje indicando que se subio el archivo, segun tu codigo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Al validar los datos puedes guardar dentro de una variable el mensaje como por ejemplo

```
//Guardamos en una variable el mensaje
$mensaje = "la ruta destino donde se guardo el archivo es: $ruta$archivo_nombre";
//Lo mandamos con un header a la pagina y le incluimos un ? para identificar 
//que sera obtenido por metodo GET
header("location: index.php?info=&msg=$mensaje");
```

Y luego dentro del index.php colocar

```
//validamos que vienen hacia la direcion con info
if(isset($_GET[info])){
$msg = $_GET[msg];
//Hacemos un echo del mensaje
echo $msg;
}
```

No soy un experto en esto, pero sin embargo ya he utilizado desde diferentes archivos esta manera para obtener diferentes mensajes dentro de la misma variable

Comment: Me indica esto:  Notice: Use of undefined constant info - assumed 'info' in  &  Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'info' in

Comment: :)  en el HTML no me muestra nada, pero en la consola me muestra el index.php con los datos de cabecera y la cadena enviada...